# How to set a property of a class to be returned by default for an object/class?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement my own list class. Just for training, to better understand how things work.

I have something like:

```
public class TestClass {
    public int[] List;
    // Add(), ...
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the array (which is the property of `TestClass`) like this:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
int[] list = testClass; // without the ".List" list would point to the array
```

and not like this:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
int[] list = testClass.List;
```

The same way that the c# build-in generic list class can be used.

How can i achieve this (if this is even possible)?

**UPDATE**

I changed the "list" to `int[]`, i hope this will help.

I know that i could just do something like:

```
int[] list = new int[10];
```

But i needed the `TestClass` because i needed some other (extended) properties about the array and more custom methods for it.

**UPDATE 2**

Maybe this will clear things up some more.

I'm trying to find out, how the generic `List<T>` class works in this case:

```
var list = new List<T>();
foreach(var oneElement in list)
```

In my case i have to do it like this:

```
var list = new TestClass();
foreach(var oneElement in list.List)
```

I want to be able to retrieve my array the same way as the `.NET` or `C#` `List<T>` class retrieves it's "underlying array".

Comment: Your `List` field is an array (i.e., a collection of fixed size), not a list (i.e., a collection of variable size).

Comment: "t's done with the c# build-in generic list class" How _what_ is done?  Do you want to implicitly cast your type to `SomeTypeOrGenericT[]`?

Comment: @DStanley exactly. Is this even possible? I want to retrieve the array.

Comment: The statement "like it's done with the build-in generic list class"  doesn't make a whole lot of sense because the `List<T>` class never gives you access to the underlying array. What feature of `List<T>` are you trying to implement? An indexer? Use in a foreach statement?

Comment: How would you expect the compiler to know the difference whether you want to assign the class or the underlying array? The syntax would be identical, so I expect you won't be able to do this exactly as you've requested.

Comment: @JoSmo Well, yeah, it;'s possible, and I even added (but deleted) an answer that does it, but I'm not sure that's the _right_ approach.  The "list" would be read-only, so you couldn't add to it like the built-in list.  I think you want to just implement the appropriate interfaces as Dmitry illustrates, but it means implementing all methods on those interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `var list` is allowed to have one of the types `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`, then you just need to implement one of the interfaces `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`:

```
public class TestClass : IList<SomeTypeOrGenericT>
{
    public SomeTypeOrGenericT[] List;
    // ...

    // members of IList<SomeTypeOrGenericT>
}
```

Comment: Which part of the `IList<>` interface makes this possible?

Comment: @JoSmo Not part. Inheritance.

Comment: With the interface i would be able to do this? `var testClass = new TestClass(); var list = testClass;` to get the array?

Comment: @JoSmo What a type of `list` is supposed to be? You can assign an array to a variable of any of the types above.

Comment: It's supposed to be an array (with the word "list" i didn't mean the List class, just a list of things, like in the real world). I have updated my question, hope that it's better now.

Comment: Check the UPDATE 2 in my question. I hope that it will help.

Comment: @JoSmo For the update 1 it is definitely impossible. You can override the `implicit` operator, but it will return copy of the original array. As for update 2, you could just inherit from the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

To use your class in a foreach statement, you should implement `IEnumerable<T>`. This is fairly straight-forward:

```
public class TestClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private static readonly int[] Empty = new int[0];

    public int[] List;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() 
    {
        int[] array = List == null ? Empty : List;
        return array.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I added a simple null check in case List never gets assigned it will not throw when enumerating.

This allows you to use it in a foreach statement, as well as use LINQ extension methods:

```
var list = new TestClass();
foreach(var oneElement in list)
{
}
```

If you want other list like features you should probably implement `IList<T>`. Also there is a base class, `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` that implements all that for you. It has overridable methods so you can update other state in your class when items are added or removed. `List<T>` has no overridable methods so its uses as a base class are limited.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**

I add this only because the OP asked for it, but I don't think it's the appropriate solution in this (or most any other) situation.

---

> I want to be able to get the list like this:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
var list = testClass;
```

Well one problem is that you're using `var`. The compiler will use the most reasonable type for `list`, which is `TestClass`, since that's what the type of `testClass` is.

You *could* add a implicit casting operator if you wanted `list` to be of a list type

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    public T[] List ;
    // ...

    public static implicit operator List<T>(TestClass<T> t)
    {
       return t.List.ToList();
    }
}
```

but then you'll have to specify the type of `list` so that the compiler knows to cast the object:

```
var testClass = new TestClass<int>();
testClass.List = new[] {1,2,3,4};
List<int> list = testClass; // can't use `var here AND cast to List<T>
```

Also note that the "list" is read-only.  You're retrieving a *copy* of the internal list.  I suspect that you instead want to implement the interfaces (and all methods) methods that `List<T>` implements rather then just exposing the underlying collection as a copy.

Comment: Check the UPDATE 2 in my question. I hope that it will help to clarify things.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you might want to create an indexer. You can do so as follows:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public object this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            // put your code here to return object i from the list
        }
        set
        {
            // put your code here to set object i in the list.
            // A variable named "value" contains the incoming value.
        }
    }
}
```

You can now access items in the list as follows:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass[0] = 100; // any object really
var item = testClass[0];
```

You might also want to look at generic classes, which are useful when creating custom containers.

Comment: I want to retrieve the whole array, not just one element. Maybe this can be done with just `public object this{`? I never used this syntax, just asking. And learning new things. :)

Comment: @JoSmo i this example, testClass itself would represent the container (it's not really an array, but behaves similarly.) I was just showing how you would access a specific item inside that container. You could also say `var container = testClass` if you want a copy of the container itself.

Comment: @Downvoter: thanks for the drive-by downvote with no explanation, especially since the question was significantly edited since I posted the answer.